# Bundle ID Blunder - But is this really an issue?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have seen a lot of documentation that describes the "correct" or "recommended" format for AppStore bundle ID's to be as follows: com.CompanyName.AppName

This certainly makes sense, and it is how we named our first two apps in the AppStore.

But do to a confusing UI change on Apple's web interface, our newest app ended up getting created in iTunes Connect with the bundle ID of simply "AppName".  This is un-editable once entered, and reportedly deleting the app to try and recreate it correctly blocks you from ever again using the app's name.  Changing the app's name at the last minute is obviously not a solution if you have invested in art, branding, and marketing.

I was unable to upload our binary until I changed the Bundle ID in the info.plist to match the "incorrect" version on iTunes Connect.  Now our app has been approved, but we haven't yet made it available in the store yet.  I know that once the Bundle ID is out in the wild, it is forever unchangeable.  I imagine that if it is to be fixed, it needs to happen now before we release our app to the world.

My question -- is there any way to salvage the situation now with having an "incorrect" bundle ID?  And - is this really a situation?

Is there any actual downside to having the bundle ID formatted the way we have it?

I have written Apple twice over the past week asking for help / advice on this situation, but have not heard back.

I see a lot of people writing about the "correct" way to format a Bundle ID, but what is the downside to being formatted incorrectly?  Other than convention, what makes one way more correct than any other anyway?

Are we facing any potential issues by going live in the store?  Should we hold our release until we hear back from Apple on this?

Thanks for sharing insight, experience, and wisdom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple never responded, but our app was approved with incorrectly formatted BundleID of just "AppName" instead of "com.CompanyName.AppName".

Our app has been selling well, and we've had no issue pushing out three updates now, so as best I can tell there are no issues to worry about.

Comment: I think it's a typical case of The Emperors New Clothes, which I experience a lot in this job. Everybody blindly follows suit, but very few stop to question why. Your answer confirmed my suspicion that it's merely convention, thank you.